# USB Type-C, how is the direction of power delivery controlled?

Tags: linux, usb

Say I have a laptop and a powerbank (or two laptops) with USB type C connected together, then how is it decided which charges which?

Is it controlled by the driver? Does Linux kernel supports such control?

**Update:**

I see this patch set (currently v14) but it's not in mainline yet.

https://lwn.net/Articles/710741/

But something called UCSI is in 4.10 already:

http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/drivers/usb/misc/Kconfig

```
270 config UCSI
271         tristate "USB Type-C Connector System Software Interface driver"
272         depends on ACPI
273         help
274           UCSI driver is meant to be used as a convenience tool for desktop and
275           server systems that are not equipped to handle USB in device mode. It
276           will always select USB host role for the USB Type-C ports on systems
277           that provide UCSI interface.
```

So is it correct to say that the Linux kernel driver for this problem is work in progress as of 4.10?

Comment: I know my android phone gives me the option to choose "Charge this device" or "Supply Power" so my assumption is it can be controlled by the driver/OS.

Comment: Good question. And it looks like this is ripe for a userspace/contrib UI to be written by the community. Would be nice to have a UI like Android has to control the flow of power.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In Linux you can control the direction of power on a given port by writing "source" or "sink" to the appropriate sysfs control, eg.:

```
# echo source >/sys/class/typec/port0/power_role
# cat /sys/class/typec/port0/power_role
[source] sink
```

The term in bracket indicates how is power currently flowing. See the kernel documentation see: https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/ABI/testing/sysfs-class-typec

Of course all of this works only if the device connected to the USB Type-C port supports Power Delivery. So it won't work with a typical Type-C power adapter or most Type-C portable batteries as they rarely support PD as of 2019.

Comment: This is actually the patch that I linked in the question. It's finally merged in the 4.19 cycle.

Comment: You can control direction of power on a "given port" if the "given port" supports Power Delivery in hardware, which includes the port on a "given gadget". Which is a very big "IF", since USB, Type-C, and PD are nearly independent specifications, and all depends on how a manufacturer of a "given device" feels about implementing all 3 together. So to believe that some "term in bracket" on some Linux terminal window controls anything is very naive.

Comment: Ale..chenski: not naive at all. If the port doesn't support PD, or if the remote device doesn't support PD, the echo command will clearly indicate it with an Input/Output Error or Operation Not Supported error. See power_role_store() in drivers/usb/typec/class.c. Whatever is shown in bracket is what is supported by the port, supported by the device, *and* successfully configured at the hardware level.

Comment: This answer makes sense, however, I am getting (even with `sudo`) the error:

`warning: An error occurred while redirecting file '/sys/class/typec/port1/power_role'
open: Permission denied`.

Comment: The file exists and I can `cat` it out just fine. Kernel 5.19.

Comment: If you do `sudo echo sink > /sys...` shell tries to open the file for writing before it runs sudo. Have you tried sudo bash -c 'echo sink > /sys...`?

Comment: @MarcBevand I'm getting `Input/output error` while trying to write to the `/sys/class/typec/port0/power_role`. Is there a way around it? My power-bank is capable of 20v@2.5A and `/sys/class/typec/port0/power_operation_mode` (while PB charges the laptop) is `usb_power_delivery`
(P.S. I'm on kernel 5.16.64)

Comment: Thanks Zaar, I tried the `sudo bash -c` wrapper and now I don't get permission denied but get "bash: line 1: echo: write error: Invalid argument".

Comment: If I echo "sink" it works, but "source" gives invalid argument. So it appears it is not liking the name of the argument. Because I tried stripping the newline out of echo with echo -n and that doesn't make a difference.

Comment: I found the source for my kernel, 6.1.8 and did verify that the two valid role names are in fact "source" and "sink", https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v6.1.8/source/drivers/usb/typec/class.c#L1312. I also tried "duel" without success.

Comment: If I unplug the power brick then I get "bash: line 1: echo: write error: Input/output error" and if it is plugged in I get "bash: echo: write error: Invalid argument". Progress!

Comment: Worth noting is that `cat /sys/class/typec/port1/vconn_source` ==  "no". I wonder if that needs to be "yes". I did an `ls -al on /sys/class/typec/port1/` and there are other file configs of note, like `supported_accessory_modes` (none), `power_operation_mode` (usb_power_delivery) and `preferred_role` (null/empty).

Comment: Updating `vconn_source` is "bash: line 1: /sys/class/typec/port1/vconn_source: Permission denied" even with the sudo bash wrapper, and then I see the file perms for root are only read, not read/write. Only files that have write are `data_role` and `power_role` so that is good to know.

Comment: The power bank I have is a RavPower PD Pioneer 20000  (Model RP-PB201) and on the back it says PD Input: 5v- 3a and so on, so it looks like it supports PD input. Maybe the kernel isn't seeing it that way though...

Comment: Still doesn't work on Lenovo Thinkpad Yoga 6, even with kernel 6.1.34

Comment: I've red [1] and the quickly unplugging and plugging back does reverse the direction.

[1] https://superuser.com/a/1690557/233703

Answer (score 5):

> USB type C connected together, then how is it decided which charges
>   which?

This is all convoluted beyond comprehension so far. Type-C connector carries two roles

1. data communication
2. power delivery.

These are nearly independent functions. The entire functionality depends on whether

1. both ports are USB hosts
2. both ports are USB devices
3. one port is Dual-role-Data and another is not
4. one port is Dual-role-power

...

n. both ports are DRD and DRP,

I lost all permutations here. The UCSI is an attempt by Microsoft to tame this vast permutivity into API standard. For major ideas, see this [presentation](http://www.usb.org/developers/presentations/USB_DevDays_Hong_Kong_2016-_UCSI.pdf), and many more publications on "UCSI interface".

Comment: Presentation link is currently "Page Not Found".

Comment: This is the same file at a different host > https://www.scribd.com/document/350194505/Usb-Devdays-Hong-Kong-2016-Usb-Pd (sign up wall though)

Answer (score 0):

As Marc's answered above, PD direction can be controlled through `/sys/class/typec/port*/power_role`, however, if it does NOT work, like it does on my Thinkpad Yoga 6:

```
sudo bash -c 'echo sink > /sys/class/typec/port1/power_role'
bash: line 1: echo: write error: Invalid argument
```

Then you can try the "hardware" method by quickly re-plugging your powerbank as mentioned by [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/1690557/233703).

Originally I was sceptical myself, but surprisingly it works! It took some practice - you need to unplug and plug it back quick but not too quick. In my case I use Romoss PPD20 powerbank and I need to unplug it for about half a second - just until the charging indicator stops flashing.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Thank you. I hope it's better